# Shared_storage_worklet error when when using chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I wrote a simple script for some web scraping application, because this website use Cloudflare bot detection so I need to use Undetected-chromedriver. Here's my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
user_data_dir = "C:\\Users\\Stack\\Desktop\\Chrome Profile\\Profile"
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True,user_data_dir=user_data_dir)
driver.maximize_window()

a = 0
driver.get("https://www.nhatot.com/mua-ban-bat-dong-san")
parent_window_handle = driver.current_window_handle
while a <= 26:
    try:
        a += 1
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul/div[1]/li/a"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(element_present)
        link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul/div["+str(a)+"]/li/a").get_attribute("href")
    except Exception as e:
        print("No listing " +str(e))
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    driver.switch_to.new_window()
    driver.get(link)
    # scrape data beep boop ........ #
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(''+str(parent_window_handle))
```

When ran the code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stack\IdeaProjects\Python Automation\Project\Profile\New Profile\test.py", line 25, in <module>
    driver.switch_to.new_window()
  File "C:\Users\Stack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 109, in new_window
    self._w3c_window(value["handle"])
  File "C:\Users\Stack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 141, in _w3c_window
    send_handle(window_name)
  File "C:\Users\Stack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 137, in send_handle
    self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_WINDOW, {"handle": h})
  File "C:\Users\Stack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Stack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevTools returned unknown type:shared_storage_worklet
  (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.95)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009B8C93+51395]
    (No symbol) [0x00925EF1]
    (No symbol) [0x007DE13A]
    (No symbol) [0x007EB131]
    (No symbol) [0x007EB4C7]
    (No symbol) [0x007DE6BC]
    (No symbol) [0x007C22ED]
    (No symbol) [0x0083F738]
    (No symbol) [0x00833E53]
    (No symbol) [0x0080C629]
    (No symbol) [0x0080D40D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D36453+3711107]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D7583A+3970154]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D70B28+3950424]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A69C99+776393]
    (No symbol) [0x009316C4]
    (No symbol) [0x0092C5A8]
    (No symbol) [0x0092C759]
    (No symbol) [0x0091DD80]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7731FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77467A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77467A6E+238]
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried to update selenium, undetected-chromedriver library but nothing work. What am I doing wrong here ?